# Mysql grant restricted to specific hours of a day

Tags: mysql, select

I'd like to know if it is possible in mysql to grant select permission to user but only within specific hours of a day.

I have created several views and new user and want to let them browse those mysql views only (for example) between 10pm and 11pm.

Comment: Please ask database admin related questions on the dedicated DBA sister site of SO.

Comment: *grant select permission to user but only within specific hours of a day* This is impossible. But you may create event procedure executed hourly which grants/revokes the permissions depends on current time.

Answer (score 0):

Edit the view criteria to be:

```
WHERE ... (previous criteria)
AND (CURRENT_USER() != 'bob@%' OR CURTIME() BETWEEN '22:00' AND '23:00')
```

This restricts the `bob` user on these times, otherwise no results are returned in the view.